# Is IEnumerable<T> Replace bad design?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods, ienumerable

I have created the following extension-methods.
Is this a bad design? Should I do this for ICollection instead?

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Replace<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> newItems)
{
    return source.Except(newItems).Union(newItems);
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> Replace<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> newItems, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    return source.Except(newItems, comparer).Union(newItems, comparer);
}
```

Update: I think the naming is little wrong. Want I want this function to do is **Add with Overwrite**.
Update: Added comparer to Union.

Comment: The first one would only be useful on Types with a broken Equality definition.

Comment: Just an observation... It's not really "replacing" is it? More "adding" or "extending"? Also, isn't the Except() superfluous?

Comment: True. If you are replacing something you need some oldItems to replace. It would be like source.Except(oldItems).Union(newItems)

Comment: May be name is incorrect. Is more like Add with Overwrite.

Comment: You are doing nothing if you are taking the same objects from the original sequence, then adding them back.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: I would think even the first would have non-trivial effect on classes with a good equality definition, by ensuring items listed in newItems will appear exactly once in the enumeration--at the end.  The name "Replace" seems odd, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplified logical operation you have is

```
 return newItems.Union(source);
 return newItems.Union(source, comparer);
```

When you take `source.Except(newItems).Union(newItems)`, you take all the distinct items in `source`, except any item in `newItems`, and then add in all the distinct items in `newItems`. That's what `Union` does! Take all the distinct items of `newItems` and add to it the distinct items from `source` that do not already exist.

You can call it by a different name `AddWithOverwrite`, `AddWithReplace`, etc., and those names would be *wrong* (nothing is being added to anything, neither the source nor newItems are modified in any way), but the operation itself needn't be as complicated as your code makes it.

There are tradeoffs. With the approach above, all of the `newItems` will come before the `source`. The counter is that you've already lost ordering with the replaced items.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you look at the original extension methods in LINQ, they all use `IEnumerable<T>` interface. If you are using generic collections, it should be enough. However your Replace method misses a parameter for members to be replaced. You should do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Replace<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> oldItems, IEnumerable<TSource> newItems)
{
    return source.Except(oldItems).Union(newItems);
}


public static IEnumerable<TSource> Replace<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> oldItems, IEnumerable<TSource> newItems, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    return source.Except(oldItems, comparer).Union(newItems);
}
```

**Update**

Here's the OverWrite method I could come up with:

```
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OverWrite<TSource, TSelectItem>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> newItems, Func<TSource, TSelectItem> selectProperty) where TSource : class
    {
        IEnumerable<TSource> result = source;

        if (newItems != null)
        {
            result = source.Select(s => newItems.FirstOrDefault(n => EqualityComparer<TSelectItem>.Default.Equals(selectProperty(s), selectProperty(n))) ?? s);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> OverWrite<TSource, TSelectItem>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> newItems, Func<TSource, TSelectItem> selectProperty,IEqualityComparer<TSelectItem> propertyComparer) where TSource : class
    {
        IEnumerable<TSource> result = source;

        if (newItems != null)
        {
            result = source.Select(s => newItems.FirstOrDefault(n => propertyComparer.Equals(selectProperty(s), selectProperty(n))) ?? s);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
someObjects.OverWrite(newObjects, item => item.ID);
someObjects.OverWrite(newObjects, item => item.ID, new PropertyComparer());
```

Comment: Yes this is more like it for Replace. However I think the naming for my method was wrong. I want to add with overwrite.

Comment: It won't help much if you are gonna overwrite with the same objects... What do you want to overwrite exactly?

Comment: you are right. But we have broken equality definition in ower objects.

Comment: I want to remove and add the new object.

Comment: I can't understand. Can you specify what objects you wanna remove?

Comment: I have List of fruits, I put a red (id=1) and yellow (id=2) apple in it. Later I have green apple with Id=1, that I want to replace the the red apple with id=1 in my collection. That is the problem.